# How to add rel='canonical' to Blogger template header

Tags: blogger, headers

How to add this to a Blogger template header:

> **rel='canonical'**

I made a mistake with `data:post.url`, which doesn't work on the header and gives me error message"

> `<link expr:href='data:post.url' rel='canonical'/>`

Comment: It's okay to answer your own question, but you need to post a clear, understandable question in the question post and create a separate answer post with your answer. Unless you're trying to answer a different question on here, in which case you should answer that question, not create a new question post. Please read our [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it my self and find the correct code

```
<b:if cond="data:blog.isMobile">
 <b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.url'>
<link expr:href='data:blog.url' rel='canonical'/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
```

the code "**data:blog.url**" retrieve correct Page url in blog 
I hope this help others . .

Answer (score 0):

This is solely automatically supported by Blogger as it’s powered by Google.

```
<b:include data="blog" name="all-head-content"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
```

I also use it on my blog